# issue while making call to jquery from angular js in implementing typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I am very beginner in angular js.I am trying to implement typeahead,which i tried to used from existing lib `<script src="lib/xyz/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>`

My input field:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id='test' name="test" ng-model="test[0].name" 
        ng-focus="formFieldJustGotFocus();" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
</div>
```

I am trying to make use of the typeahead function of the existing lib but as its an angular application,I am not sure how to make call to the function in my Controller functions test() :

```
$scope.formFieldJustGotFocus  = function test(){
             $('#test').typeahead({
            name: 'accounts',
            local: ['Audi', 'BMW', 'Bugatti', 'Ferrari', 'Ford', 'Lamborghini', 'Mercedes Benz', 'Porsche', 'Rolls-Royce', 'Volkswagen']
        });
    };
```

Comment: sorry forget to add the lib and my input field 
lib/xyz/typeahead.bundle.js and my Input field as shown below

<div>
         <input type="text" id='test'  name="test"  ng-focus="formFieldJustGotFocus($event);" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">
        </div>

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-typeahead-widget-with-angularjs/

Comment: Please first read up some angular documentation. Then you'll soon find out that you need to create a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for this, instead of doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please refer below link will help you more. it is example of typeahead with angular js.
[Typeahead example](https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv)

```
 [\[1\]: https://codepen.io/joe-watkins/pen/EagEWv][1]
```